# How to include null values for a field filtered using a like expression in a STATIC query

Tags: soql

I would like to use a static query that pulls out data using a `LIKE` operator which includes `null` values. For example, for the following data:

```
================================
|   ID   |   CategoryName__c   |
================================
|   01   |   "category one"    |
|   02   |   "category two"    |
|   03   |   "category two"    |
|   04   |       (null)        |
================================
```

I would like to be able to, in a single SOQL static query, pull out all four record regardless of their value. For example:

```
[SELCT ID, Name FROM ExampleTable__c WHERE CategoryName__c LIKE :magic]
```

Where `magic` is some string. I have tried different variations of `%` for this magic value, but it does not pick up `null` values. The purpose of this is to be able to filter on one category, or not filter on any (depending upon the user input).

I could have an `if statement` and two SOQL statements, but it would be so much nicer to just have one statement.

If I were not being restricted to static queries, I would solve my problem easily like this:

```
String sqlStatement = 'SELCT ID, Name FROM ExampleTable__c ';
if(singleCategoryOnly){
    sqlStatement += 'CategoryName__c LIKE ' + userSelectedCategory;
}
//execute statement....
```

Comment: have you tried list<exampletable__c> = database.query(yourquerystring) ;

Comment: @theGreatDanton; as my question states, I want to use a `STATIC` query...

Comment: in the second part of your question you are constructing a string which you want to execute, right??

Comment: @theGreatDanton, right: and the ellipsis represents everything else (including your code). I know how to do that. My question is about `STATIC` queries. What you are suggesting is not a `STATIC` query. The last part was to say that I know how to do it if I did not have to use static queries (in order to avoid people giving such an answer...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have figured out a solution. Not as elegant as I was hoping for, but it works. If you can think of a more elegant solution, then I will still award the answer to you.

```
String categoryOne;
String categoryTwo;

if(userSelectedACategory){
    categoryOne = categoryTwo = userSelection;
}
else{
    categoryOne = '%';//for all categories
    categoryTwo = null;//for records not set to a category
}
[SELECT ID FROM CategoryName__c WHERE (CategoryName__c = :categoryOne OR CategoryName__c = :categoryTwo) AND ... ];
```

Note, it is possible to extend this idea to dates and ranges of dates.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... WHERE CategoryName__c LIKE :key OR CategoryName__c = NULL`

Remember to group using parenthesis if you mix `AND` and `OR` keywords.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough. This answer will not fulfil my requirements. I want to be able to filter on either a specific category (records with that category only), or none at all (all records).